# Using math filters in shopify with properties gives 0 works fine with hard codded values

Tags: shopify, shopping-cart, liquid

I have calculated the total order price before for loop validated the value by printing in output. Mentioned below is the code block for the same:

```
{% assign total_items_price = 0 %}
    {% for line_item in line_items %}
        {%assign total_items_price = total_items_price | plus:line_item.price %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Following are the scenarios that I have implemented to further calculations:

1. Trying to divide the each items price by total_items_price, but the output is 0. Even if I convert it into money format result remains same:

   ```
   {{ line_item.price | divided_by:total_items_price }} 
   {{ line_item.price | divided_by:total_items_price | money }}
   ```

   2. I have used multiple math filters also but result is 0:

      {{ line_item.price | divided_by:total_items_price | times:discounts_amount}}
         {{ line_item.price | divided_by:total_items_price | times:discounts_amount | money }}

Values of variables/properties(line_item.price, total_items_price, discounts_amount) are available inside the for loop validated by printing on UI. If I use some hard coded values instead of properties/variable it gives the correct output. for ex:

```
    {{ line_item.price | divided_by:5 }} //gives the correct output
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you might use the forloop.length value. As you do not have any conditional statement inside your loop a manual indexation is not necessary.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You should try using a math filter on line_item.price.

```
{% assign total_items_price = 0 %}
{% for line_item in line_items %} 
   {% assign total_items_price = total_items_price | plus: line_item.price %} 
   {{ line_item.price | times: 1.0 | divided_by: total_items_price }} 
{% endfor %}
```

Notice the "times: 1.0" filter applied after line_item.price on line 4.